# loading all the files on a folder

Tags: python, file-io, matplotlib

I am trying to load all the txt files from the folder and plot them. Which way is the easiest to load all txt files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match all the files in a particular folder that are `.txt` files, why not use the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module?

```
import pylab, glob

txt_files = glob.iglob("./*.txt")

for data in txt_files:
    data = pylab.loadtxt(data)
    pylab.plot(data[:,1], data[:,2])

pylab.show()
```

Comment: Just beat me to it. Nice suggestion.

Comment: glob module looks like what I needed! thanks Sean. Although, I got this error: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple for the line 6

Comment: I can't make glob module work with non-integer inputs. What am I missing again?

Comment: Sean's code is missing the line where you actually load the text files using either `pylab.loadtxt` or `np.loadtxt`. You should change it to: `for data_file in txt_files: data = pylab.loadtxt(data_file). . .`

Comment: @Josh, @Chad -- fixed the issue.  Everything should work now.  Thanks for the heads up Josh!

Comment: OK guys now I have too many lines plotted which makes it nonsense :) is there any chance to show the file names on each particular line plotted?

Comment: @Chad: If there are too many lines to make sense of, adding text to each line is likely not going to improve the situation. However you could modify the for loop to plot each data file in a separate window, or if you don't have too many plots use subplots. I don't have the space in the comments to show you the code though.

Comment: I think its better if I plot 10 files at a time and I can manage to arrange the loop for that.

Comment: How do I do adding the file name as a text to each line?